# NSMutableArray not changing on event like expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can loop through them just fine but what I'd like to do is change the background color (still new to objective c). Here's what I have:

```
@interface MYViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listImages;
@end

@implementation MYViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.listImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem-highlighted.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem-highlighted.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-menuitem-highlighted.png"], nil];

    [self.listImages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something with object
        UIImage *image = [self.listImages objectAtIndex:idx];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100*idx, 10*idx, imageView.frame.size.width + 15, imageView.frame.size.height + 15);

        [imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    }];
    [self.view addSubview:btnEventClick];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)myEventDo:(DoEvent *)btnEventClick {
    NSLog(@"My event is doing!");
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *item in self.listImages) {
        NSLog(@"hi");
        UIImage *newImage = [self.listImages objectAtIndex:i++];
        UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
        newImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result are you getting with the code you have now? What is eventClick? What is newImageView? This line, is wrong, for (NSString *item in self.listImages) -- listImages contains images, not strings (and you don't do anything with item anyway).

Comment: @rdelmar Hi, sorry, I tried to shorten everything for the sake of brevity. "btnEventClick" is just a button, the result I'm getting with NSLog is just "hi" in the console but I'm not getting any changes with the background color. Would you like for me to include the file containing the "btnEventClick"?

Comment: well - you take an `UIImage` from the array - you add it to a newly created `UIImageView` and you set the color of that `UIImageView` .. nothing is supposed to change by your code

Comment: You're creating several image views and adding them as subviews in viewDidLoad, but then you create new image views in myEventDo, which are never added as subviews. That's what's wrong. You need to get a reference to the ones you already created, not make new ones.

Comment: @rdelmar @ rokjarc sorry, I was just testing some things out. Maybe a dumb question, but what would be the best way to reference the ones already created?

Comment: I would create another mutable array, and add the image views to it as you create them. You can then access them in myEventDo in a for-in loop.

Comment: @rdelmar trying that out now, will edit in the result afterwards, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting backgroundColor on a brand new UIImageView and then not displaying it. Personally, I'd create another array of UIImageView objects when you create those and modify those objects. Something like:

```
@interface otViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listImages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listImageViews;
@end

@implementation otViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.listImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"S.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"X.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"O.png"], nil];
    self.listImageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.listImageViews count]];

    [self.listImages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something with object
        UIImage *image = [self.listImages objectAtIndex:idx];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100*idx, 10*idx, imageView.frame.size.width + 15, imageView.frame.size.height + 15);

        [imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [self.listImageViews addObject:imageView];

    }];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"My event is doing!");

    for (UIImageView *item in self.listImageViews) {
        NSLog(@"hi");
        item.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

}
```

Also rdelmar is correct, your array is of UIImage objects, not NSString objects.